# Why does a falling ladder $y$ component force greater than the $x$ component force?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, rotational-dynamics, torque

I have a ladder at 30* against the smooth wall and it accelerates down and to the left when it falls to a rough ground. It also pivots at the bottom. I understand that the the force of gravity is greater than the ground normal force because it accelerates down. I understand that the wall normal force is greater than the force of friction on the floor because it accelerates to the left. However, I don't understand why the Y component force is greater than the X component force. What is both the conceptual way mathematical way to explain this.

Comment: Does Dale answer your question and if  not, why?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the path of the center of mass. It is accelerating more down than it is horizontally. Therefore, by $F=ma$ the vertical component of the force must be larger than the horizontal component.

Comment: Hello Dale. I agree with your answer, but can you explain to the OP why the center of  mass accelerates more down than horizontally based on "looking at the path of the center of mass"? I believe it can be explained in terms of the constraints on the movement of the center of mass due to the wall and ground, but I'd like to see your explanation.

Comment: BTW My granddaughter has something in common with you as she has a BS in Biomedical Engineering (Yeah, I'm that old) . She started a PHD in BE at Cornell but decided  instead to get a job as a data scientist (whatever that is!)  while pursuing a masters in computer science from NYU.